# Visual Studio C++ preprocessor-define fails with path starting on "u"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive, unicode-escapes

That's right I want to supply a path as preprocessor define (properties->configuration->c/c++->preprocessor)

```
MY_PATH=c:\$(WindowsSdkDir)\um
```

But this hits me upon use with

```
E1696 cannot open source file "C:\asdf\u0000m\xyz.h"
E0992 command-line error: invalid macro definition: MY_PATH=c:\asdf\um
```

Because visual studio seemingly sees \u as a unicode escape. However, there is no way to escape the backslash, so now I cant specify any path that contains a directory starting on u.
I also cant switch to / as a path separator because I pull in environment variables that use .

What to do?

I am on latest Windows 10 with latest SDK and Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: `MY_PATH=c:\$(WindowsSdkDir)\um` is a statement of what language? Doesn't look like C++. Is is a Makefile? Is it a powershell script? The preprocessor by itself is just fine with paths like this, literal or passed via a command line option '/Dvar=value'

Comment: weird, preprocessor macro has nothing to do with source opening so `E1696 cannot open source file "C:\asdf\u0000m\xyz.h"` is probably unrelated to it

Comment: Also, are those compiler errors or intellisense errors?

Comment: @phuclv you can do `#include SOME_MACRO`

Comment: n.1, that would be what vs calls a "macro". It can be used in msvc preprocessor defines, at least if they are specified in the VS GUI / in the vcxproj file. phuclv is right, i then go on to use the define in an include statement. I get it both as intelisense and compile error.

Comment: So this is a statement in a vcxproj file?

Comment: Yes. Under <PreprocessorDefinitions>. Can be edited via GUI right-click on projectfile properties -> configuration-> c/c++ -> preprocessor

Comment: I would try to replace either \ or `u` with their `%xx` equivalents as per [msbuild docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-msbuild?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Good Idea! Unfortunately, same problem...

Comment: Can you see the actual command line that runs the compiler? Should be in the build logs.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for anything that requires escaping instead

```
char const * ddd = R"(C:\asdf\u0000m\xyz.h)";
```

No more escaping required and the result is much more readable. So in this case on the command line you'll use

```
 -DMY_PATH=R\"\(C:\\asdf\\u0000m\\xyz.h\)\"
```

because you only need to escape for the shell and not the C++ source code

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:3),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Achar+const+*+ddd+%3D+MY_PATH%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++printf(%22%25s%22,+MY_PATH)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.6611678449856,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-DMY_PATH%3DR%5C%22%5C(C:%5C%5Casdf%5C%5Cu0000m%5C%5Cxyz.h%5C)%5C%22%27,selection:(endColumn:40,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:40,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:20,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:20,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x64+msvc+v19.latest+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.3388321550144,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:49.3388321550144,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Thanks! But it seems this isnt supported when I need to add the ppdefine to my .vcxproj or use the built-in property editor in VS... Also I need to  resolve environment variables in the path...

Comment: @berndfeinman Entering `MY_PATH=R"(c:\$(WindowsSdkDir)\um)"` in the properties in Visual Studio works for me. Printing `std::string s = MY_PATH;` results in `c:\C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\um`, as expected. (Naturally, prepending "c:\" makes no real sense, but that is what you wrote in the original post.) In the vcprojx file, it looks the same: `<PreprocessorDefinitions>MY_PATH=R"(c:\$(WindowsSdkDir)\um)";%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>`. If it doesn't work for you, you need to post more information (e.g. the relevant part of the vcprojx and the source).

Comment: Thanks! I am getting the same issue though - but! meanwhile I have found out the bug is related to msvc two phase lookup. So sometimes you can get lucky and it will magically work with "rebuild". Even better turning off /Zc:twoPhase- ... I will report more tomorrow. Meanwhile, can you try to hit rebuild a couple of times or build new with minor modification on your end and see if it works always?

Comment: It's a header name. Header names are *not* string literals though they look pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

Use four backslashes: `-DMY_PATH=\"C:\\\\asdf\\\\u0000m\\\\xyz.h\"`

https://godbolt.org/z/9Yn4csjv1

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesnt work. Perhaps unclear - the 0000 are inserted by VS mistakenly, the actual directory name is "um". If i rename it "vm" it works fine.
With four slashes, the 0000 are still inserted...

I need to put the ppdefine inside my .vcxproj.

Comment: Hmm that sounds like file encoding problem. Make sure your vcxproj is saved in utf-8

Comment: It is. It even happens when I input the path with the VS GUI. Seems like a VS bug?

Comment: Yeah, I bet it is